# Facebook logout button creeps across the screen in Firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook, macos, firefox, facebook-login

Go to our website here http://readabout.me/ and click the login with Facebook button in the bottom right-hand corner of the page. After going through the steps to sign in with our app, the login button will change to a logout button and start slowly creeping across the screen, lol.

It looks like the Facebook resize JavaScript is being called over and over again on the login button for some reason, but I can't figure it out. I've had good luck with JavaScript debugging here on Stack Overflow before, so hopefully you guys can help me out :-)

Thanks a bunch! I promise you, this is one of the strangest HTML/JS bugs you will come across, ha ha.

Philip

PS I'm using Firefox on Mac OS X. It seems to work fine in all other browsers.

PPS Here's an animated gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBpwd.gif

[image]

Comment: +1 for the quality of that GIF giving me a good laugh. Now I'll try to answer your question...

Comment: Ha ha, I don't have much experience creating animated gifs, so I just used ffmpeg, and to keep it under 2 MB for imjur I gave it 0.33 Hz, or one frame per 3 seconds, lol.

Comment: Its silly GIFs can't be compressed better. Anywho, on topic: I'm opening in FF 13.0.1 on Mac and can't replicate the behavior. It has a somewhat choppy switch to the logout button but it stays put for me. Edit: It says "logout" but clicking it asks me to give more FB permissions, and it still says "Still have an account? [FB|Logout]" which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate question. It appears to be a bug on facebook.

[How to prevent the facebook-SDK (Javascript) is moving the logout button from right to left ("PluginResize")](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11402525/how-to-prevent-the-facebook-sdk-javascript-is-moving-the-logout-button-from-ri/11410112#11410112)